# How to initialize the redux-form with dirty set true?

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a save button binded to the dirty state, when form is dirty, enable the button, otherwise disable it.

This is good for editing an item. But when I add an item, the save button is disabled by default, because dirty is *false* by default.

Is there a way to set the form to dirty state?

Answer (score 1):

According to  [Action Creators documentation](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/) of redux-form, you can do it when you initialize data for your form:

```js
import { initialize } from 'redux-form';

export const initializeForm = (formName, newData) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(initialize(formName, newData, false));
};
```

Also, you can set additional options in that function f.e

```js
import { initialize } from 'redux-form';

export const initializeFormWithOldValues = (formName, newData) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(initialize(formName, newData, false, { keepSubmitSucceeded: true, keepValues: true }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered the question yet.

What I am doing now is to create a `canSave` prop to my component.
`canSave && dirty` can determine the visibility status of the save button.
When adding an item, `canSave` is set to true, save button is always visible.
When editing an item, `canSave` is false, the visibility is determined on `dirty` prop.

I'm still hoping to find a more elegant answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the save button state yourself. All you need to do is to not enable the Save/Submit button